# Training on bigdata h5 file create in Julia via h5 in python

Tags: python, julia, bigdata, training-data, h5py

I have an h5 file which was created in Julia.
I need to practice training but unsure of how to work with big-data.

```
feature_matrix = h5py.File('features.h5','r')
```

This file has dataset which has following architecture e.g.

```
Path: /feature1 
Shape: (900000,)
Data type: float32

Path: /feature2 
Shape: (900000,)
Data type: float32

Path: /label 
Shape: (900000,)
Data type: float32
```

which is derived from code at
https://www.titanwolf.org/Network/q/8a9ac510-a806-4504-8c61-1a8720717dab/y
If I extract the features (70) into a matrix, it'll be too big to process. How should I combine features separately and keep label separately to train a model?